# How do I use OpenSSH network tunneling in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh, vpn

I want to use the OpenSSH tunneling capability that is described in [this wiki entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN), in which SSH tunnels all traffic at OSI level  2 or 3 via virtual network devices on both ends, a.k.a. tun/tap. I have this working from a Linux client to a Linux host, but I'd like to connect via *Windows* client to the same Linux host.

Ideally this would be a plugin for OpenConnect, but I haven't seen such a capability there, at least not yet. I assume something like the [OpenVPN Windows tun/tap driver](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/GettingTapWindows) and an SSH client would be involved.

To clarify, I'm **not** trying to:

- Use standard SSH port-forwarding
- Use SSH as a SOCKS proxy
- Tunnel OpenVPN over SSH with port-forwarding